# Use of plural forms when using "Multi-xxx"

Tags: adjectives, grammatical-number

Which one is correct? A **multi-languages** university or A **multi-language** university? A **multi-outlet** socket or A **multi-outlets** socket?

Comment: multi-language university. See also three-hour flight, ten-man team, five-piece set, etc

Comment: no need to use plural form.

Answer (score 1):

As [curious-proofreader said in a comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/327544/use-of-plural-forms-when-using-multi-xxx/507175#comment746347_327544):

> multi-language university. See also three-hour flight, ten-man team, five-piece set, etc